# How to only read in lines from a textfile if they fit a specific criteria?

Tags: java

I have a text file that I can now scan, however there are certain lines within the file that I don't want to read in, is there a way to only read in a line if it starts with a capital letter?
Please help a nooby?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Perhaps only a small change is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward problem, pretty simple solution:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!line.isEmpty() && Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(0)))
           System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    // Handle the trouble
}
```

Simply check if the line you just read (provided non-empty and not null as checked in the if-statement) starts with  an uppercase letter, otherwise it will move on to the next line.

Comment: Which throws a nice `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on empty lines... And calling `br.close();` is redundant, the try-with-resources takes care of it.

Comment: `if(line != null` is still redundant, you're in a while loop where this is true.

Comment: Well, okay how about now? I think it's all proper. Shouldn't have rushed this one...

Comment: You're still missing a parentheses, it doesn't compile. You should take your time, run your code in an IDE before posting it. Why rush? Make a good and clear answer, it wins all the time.